# Как настроить, чтобы хост GitLab Pages смотрел в нужную папку?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Структура на данный момент следующая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По-умолчанию, он смотрит в корень и берет оттуда файл index.html.

Однако все скомпилированные файлы находятся в корневой папке dist/.

Попытка сконфигурировать файл

```
gitlab-ci.yml
```

по неопытности результатов не дала.

Как настроить, чтобы корневой для хоста была именно директория dist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените job с именем pages в .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
  script:
  - mv dist public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

---

Причём, вариант

```
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist
```

работать не будет(ошибка появится во внутреннем pages:deploy).